# Consecutive Transactions Eventually Promote To MSDTC

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, msdtc

We have the following setup: EF 5 (now 6 as of today), Ado.NET, Sql Server 2012, .NET 4.5 C#.

We have a service and generic repository using a mix of EF and Ado.NET for more complex queries/updates for performance.  We have been wrapping these in TransactionScope and everything works fine.  However we are occasionally getting MSDTC errors as we have this service turned off to stop it promoting to a distributed transaction.

We also manage the connection and transaction per request so a single Sql Connection is created per request, shared with EF and any ado.net actions and a transaction is only created when we do any Ado.NET updates anb/or EF.  This works absolutely fine, everything takes part in the transaction and if the connection is created before the transaction we use:

```
EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current);
```

So why is is sometimes promoting to MSDTC after multiple sucessive requests as the log here shows:

http://www.filedropper.com/warn-2013-10-18 (if there is a better way to share files please let me know)

It always seems to happen around the 15th transaction scope.  Is it a case of no more connections in the pool?

I have been banging my head around this for a few days and would appreciate any help.  As the log shows here for example: Transaction Identifier: eb18070a-77e4-4617-8fbb-63e416f5ab9c:15.

Comment: I'm not qualified to answer your question, but now that you are using EF6 you could consider controlling your transactions directly instead of using TransactionScope https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Improved%20Transaction%20Support

Comment: We are using ObjectContext with POCO classes and an EDMX designer, I have looked at moving to DbContext but not sure of the benefits and didn't like that it seems to generate a migration table to track model changes.  I'll give this a try though just in case as it looks interesting and could be the solution.  I'm quite nervous about transaction scope as it seems to still escalate for unknown reasons and we don't want to use MSDTC for performance reasons.

Comment: I tried changing from transaction scope to a SqlTransaction using DbContext.Database.UseTransaction but unfortunately we get other errors regarding MultipleActiveResultSets=True which causes New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.  Could this be what is causing the TransactionScope to escalate to MSDTC?